# Does git-flow enforce linear histories on some branches

Tags: git, git-flow

I am still trying to move from git towards git-flow. I know I can use any kind of git feature within git-flow, but I am mostly interested in what it handles automatically.

Let's assume there are two developers Alice and Bob, working on feature A and B respectively. When Alice is done, she can do a `git flow feature finish A` to create a merge commit on her local `develop` branch based on commit C. Now if Bob finishes his feature at the same time, and he fetched the same stuff, his merge commit will also be based on C. Now if Alice pushes and then bob fetches again, he will have to merge or rebase and we end up with a non-linear history on the `develop` branch, in case he merges.

Is this correct so far, or does git-flow somehow handle this situation automatically? If there is some automatic mechanism, what will have to be set up for this to work?

The simplest solution would probably be to always fetch `develop` before finishing features. However I am not sure that this is actually possible, depending on the way the repository is shared (might not be available at that time).

**EDIT** (clarifications of the problem):

As the answers suggest, my example was not clear. So first a picture of what I think is the problem:

C is the initial commit on the develop branch.

Alice creates some feature work on the feature branch:

```
develop    feature/A
|           |
v           v
C-A1-A2-A3-A4
```

At the same time Bob also does work for another feature

```
C-A1-A2-A3-A4
 \
  B1-B2-B3-B4
```

Now Alice finishes the feature and the merge commit is added to develop (I want that).

```
  A1-A2-A3-A4
 /           \
C-  -  -  -   MA
```

Now Bob finishes the feature and again a merge commit is added to develop (I also want that, just at another place:

```
  A1-A2-A3-A4
 /           \
C-  -  -  -   MA <- develop for Alice
 \
  \ -  -  -   - MB <-develop for Bob
   \           /
    B1-B2-B3-B4
```

However now either Alice or Bob has to merge develop, creating an additional commit:

```
  A1-A2-A3-A4
 /           \
C-  -  -  -   MA-MAB <- I don't want this MAB commit
 \               / 
  \ -  -  -   - MB <-develop for Bob
   \           /
    B1-B2-B3-B4
```

What I would like to have instead would be something like this:

```
  A1-A2-A3-A4
 /           \
C-  -  -  -   MA-MB
 \               / 
  B1-B2-B3-B4- -
```

As you can see, the history is still non-linear, however the main line of the develop branch only contains the merge commits from features (and no additional merge commits as in the other case).

What I like about this, is that you can easily follow changes in the history and see if they belong to former feature branches or if they were merges in develop. All this information can be derived directly from the DAG.

Also if you use good messages for your merge commits on develop, in the second case you can easily derive a changelog, by always following the first parent on develop. However in the second case you sometimes need to follow the first parent only and sometimes more than one parent. And I cannot see an easy way when to do which that I could code up.

Comment: What's wrong with nonlinear history? Merges have substantial meaning; they mark for example that you merged a bugfix into a stable branch, which is an inherent part of the workflow you're trying to use. If you force a nonlinear history on yourself, you lose that.

Comment: @Jefrom: I guess I was not able to explain precisely what I meant. I updated the question to clarify that I am not interested in a completly linear history, but rather that I am trying to preserve the meaning of first/second parents in the case of merges on branches.

Comment: Okay, well, in any case, `git-flow` still doesn't do any of it. I can edit my answer to remove the reasons *why* it doesn't do it, but... the answer does answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-flow` does nothing like that.

It's intended to support [the branching model described here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (which is really just a pretty picture for the kinds of things Git developers recommend). **That picture includes merges.** You'll see the same all through the text. Under each type of branch, you'll see the types of branches they should be *merged* into. There are example commands, using `--no-ff` to forcibly *avoid* linear history, and instead record merge commits.

This is a workflow that really uses Git, and one of Git's core strengths is branching and merging. This workflow thrives on merging; nonlinear history is not only unavoidable but *desired*.

You should read the section titled "Incorporating a finished feature on develop" from the description of the workflow. A short quote:

> The --no-ff flag causes the merge to always create a new commit object, even if the merge could be performed with a fast-forward. This avoids losing information about the historical existence of a feature branch and groups together all commits that together added the feature.
>
> ...
>
> Unfortunately, I have not found a way to make --no-ff the default behaviour of git merge yet, but it really should be.

You want those merge commits. You really do.

Comment: Ok, I guess my example was not clear. I did not mean to keep a completely flat history, but only simplify some branches. I'll try to update the question to make clear what I mean.

Comment: @LiKao: I understood your example, but I'd still argue that nonlinear history is not bad. In any case, `git-flow` isn't going to do anything automatically to modify your history. It only wraps a few simple operations - mostly branch creation and resolution.

Comment: Well, I can see the significance of both the MA and MB commits, which I do want. However I cannot see any added informative value of the MAB commit, which I am trying to get rid of (just played around a little and noticed, that it is actually not so easy). Could you be more precise about the added information this MAB commit gives?

Comment: @LiKao: That one may not give as much information. Obviously the others are more meaningful. But I still wouldn't really mind having it - it indicates a division of labor, and sometimes you care about which developer you need to track down to talk to about a given change. If you want to magic it away with a rebase, go for it. You'll have to do it manually though!

Comment: “(which is really just a pretty picture for the kinds of things Git developers recommend)” Where have they recommended that? I haven’t seen the `--no-ff` merges of `develop` into `master` recommended by anything/anyone else than that page. (And people who like Git Flow.)

Comment: @Guildenstern Did you notice when this answer was written, and the note at the top of the linked page? :) Git's own git repository at the time looked like this, and git-flow was based on practices like that.

Comment: @Cascabel I did notice the date. I just haven’t seen anyone else claim (like in the linked article) that this is what the Git project did back in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Jefromi is right about that there is no harm in having that `MAB` merge in the history.

There is a way to avoid this commit, by the way that the one (lets say this is B), who pushes his feature merge to the central repo, does not merge the other merge commit (here `MA`) into the own history. Instead the second one has to destroy the local merge commit(`MB`), and redo the merge, where the first parent now is not `C`, but the merge commit of the first one(`MA`). So the second developer now creates a merge which contains the other merge and the own branch (the new `MB`).

Personally I wouldn't care about the `MAB` commit, but doesn't want to explain all the steps needed to get the `MAB` free history to people new to git.